Stripe Apple pay integration in laravel
i dont have any vedio on the youtube that help me to integrate the stripe apple pay integration i dont know how the integrate the apple pay i use chat gpt and other source is it complesry for apple pay of stripe integration in laravel we have mac book
i use chatgpt and bard and stripe documentation but it is useless help me please

Please write your question in a clear way that makes it easy to understand. At the bare minimum please use proper grammar and punctation so that people can understand what you are saying and help you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
